# Downloading image in titanium from parse

Tags: parse-platform, titanium

I need to download images from parse and I am new to titanium. How to do this. I have search the web but no help found regarding the download there are some code available for upload images.

Comment: Have u been able to download parse object if yes share the code so that could tell you then how to download it

Answer (score 1):

HI this can help you parsing the images.

```
var request = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient({
onload: function(e) {
    var result=JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    console.log(result.url);
},
onerror: function(e) {
    alert(e.message);
}
});

// Register device token with Parse
request.open('POST', 'https://api.parse.com/1/files/pic.jpg', true);
request.setRequestHeader('X-Parse-Application-Id', 'MY_APP_KEY');
request.setRequestHeader('X-Parse-REST-API-Key', 'MY_REST_KEY');
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');
request.send(image);
```

Thanks

PRASHAANTH